# import libvirt in python but ImportError on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, kvm, libvirt

My os is Ubuntu 12.04.
I install the kvm virt-manager and python.
I want to use python code to control the vm on kvm.
but my code import libvirt has something wrong...

Here is my code :

```
import libvirt
import time
import threading
import paramiko
import os
import commands
import signal

numVM = 1
hostname=['VM-01']
port=22
VMLoadAve={}
def monitor():
     ..... 
     while True:
         monitor() 
         time.sleep(MAXDURATION)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test1.py", line 1, in
>   
>       import libvirt ImportError: No module named libvirt

I have installed the python-libvirt, libvirt-bin 
what other reasons may do this happened?
I am a newest for this.  thanks for your help ~ :)

Comment: It looks up for `libvirt` and you have `python-libvirt` and `libvirt-bin`, which aparently are not the same. Could you please provide the addition info? What exactly test1.py contains?

Comment: hello, here is my code...

import libvirt
import time
import threading
import paramiko
import os
import commands
import signal

numVM = 1
hostname=['VM-01']
port=22

VMLoadAve={}
def monitor():
.....
while True:
        monitor()
        time.sleep(MAXDURATION)

Comment: here is my part code.

Comment: Do you have `./site-packages/libvirt.py` in your python directory (in my case it's /usr/lib/python3.4)

Comment: It seems that I can't find ./site-packages/libvirt.py, maybe I lose something when I install the python.. or do you do additional step when you install? thanks!

Comment: You may try to 'sudo find / -name libvirt.py' on your root. It seems like it installed on wrong directory, python version or installing has failed. I'm using ArchLinux and I have not issues with `libvirt-python3` package.

Comment: I reinstall my ubuntu and do it again. it works!  thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of historicaly record, 'python-libvirt' is the correct deb package for the python 2 binding, while python3-libvirt gives you the corresponding python 3 binding to libvirt.